# Tortoise HG Workbench - do NOT put repos in C:\Windows\System32

Tags: tortoisehg

When I install Tortoise HG Workbench and go to clone a repo, it always wants to put the repo into  C:\Windows\system32

Which is absolutely where I would never want to put anything!  Is there a way to change this default?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and came across this post hoping for an answer.  Unfortunately, no answer was here.  Fortunately, I just figured it out.  I have the program pinned to my Windows taskbar.  I right-clicked the icon, right-clicked "TortoiseHg Workbench", and selected "Properties".  In the "Start in:" field, I entered the desired default path.